# Go append a string to an array of array of interface

Tags: arrays, go, go-interface

Trying to add a string to an initialised array of array of interfaces.

```
matrix := [][]interface{}{{"cat", "cat", "cat"}}
a := [][]interface{}{{"tiger"}}
matrix = append(matrix, a...)
```

Output:

```
[[cat cat cat] [tiger]]
```

But I wanted tiger in together with `[[cat cat cat tiger]]` like this.

Comment: matrix[0] = append(matrix[0], a[0][0])

Comment: what does `matrix := [][][[cat cat cat] [tiger]]{}{{"cat", "cat", "cat"}}` mean? It's not valid Go code.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an array of interface (`a...`) to `matrix` an array of array of interface:
your array of array (`matrix`) has now two arrays.

You would need to add to the first element of that array (matrix`[0]`), in order to keep *one* array inside your array of array.

Example: https://goplay.tools/snippet/QcPTYIh1wJR

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    matrix := [][]interface{}{{"cat", "cat", "cat"}}
    a := [][]interface{}{{"tiger"}}
    matrix = append(matrix, a...)
    fmt.Println("matrix :", matrix)

    matrix2 := [][]interface{}{{"cat", "cat", "cat"}}
    b := append(matrix2[0], a[0]...)
    matrix2[0] = b
    fmt.Println("matrix2: ", matrix2)
}
```

Output:

```golang
matrix : [[cat cat cat] [tiger]]
matrix2:  [[cat cat cat tiger]]
```